# NHibernate version confusion

Tags: .net, nhibernate

OK, hit me over the head if this is a blatantly duplicate question....
I recently purchased NHibernatie in Action from Manning. This book outlines version 1.21
It mentions a version 2.0 of NHibernate that is coming/is in beta. If I download NHibernate from nhforge I get version 2.1 Is the book hopelessly outdated??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the book is a little outdated, but the concepts, and code are still core. the book I found to be a great read and a good source to understand Nhibernate.

the latest version of the library is 2.1. the main thing i have noticed is the proxyfactory which you can setup in the config file ([upgrading to 2.1](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/upgrading-to-nhibernate-21/)). the mapping files are the same (you can use [Fluent Nhiberate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) instead)

but this said, the book describes how the Session, Transations and other aspects of the library extremely well.

also look at this video cast series http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/ and http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/NHibernate

HTH

Bones

Comment: I've read through most of the book myself.  Though I was and am initially disappointed that it didn't cover the then current 2.0.1 changes,  I believe provides a solid backbone of understanding.  If only there was a place to go after the book that doesn't involve community posts and guesswork.

Comment: there is the reference manual <http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html> this is very deep in detail. this is located on the offical community site <http://nhforge.org/>. If you are after commerical support look at <http://www.nhprof.com/CommercialSupport>, which is also home to the NH profiler